# Deploy syncfusion example in Heroku

Tags: heroku

I tried to run the web-assembly of this https://github.com/syncfusion/blazor-showcase-appointment-planner in Heroku.

I added the buildpack https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack in Heroku, and try to deploy it. Here is the log after building it in Heroku:

```
2021-10-20T05:11:46.910345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `cd /app/heroku_output && ./HealthTracker.Client`

2021-10-20T05:11:47.575776+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: ./HealthTracker.Client: No such file or directory

2021-10-20T05:11:47.685283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127

2021-10-20T05:11:47.893064+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2021-10-20T05:12:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2021-10-20T05:12:49.235940+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=testing1020.herokuapp.com request_id=b3604c45-79db-4ff4-8a39-5b2120c831f5 fwd="219.78.255.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-10-20T05:12:50.208185+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=testing1020.herokuapp.com request_id=cee0dbd6-a639-4348-a292-401e4f119edd fwd="219.78.255.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-10-20T05:22:08.275777+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=testing1020.herokuapp.com request_id=4ecd0252-1e70-437d-ba12-787499e10715 fwd="219.78.255.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-10-20T05:22:11.799657+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=testing1020.herokuapp.com request_id=7823761f-d163-4392-b76f-7af4fdae256b fwd="219.78.255.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

2021-10-20T05:22:12.075022+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=testing1020.herokuapp.com request_id=efeaffb9-954e-4737-9ca0-a138a3568ac5 fwd="219.78.255.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

I tried to remove web-assembly away from the folder tree, and move its contents to the root of the repository. I then get:

```
2021-10-20T05:11:47.575776+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: ./HealthTracker.Client: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone deploy the app in Heroku, or spot any error in the deploying process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone with the same problem here. It's not the desired solution, but it works. I didn't manage to push my Blazor WASM project neither to Heroku (with .net buildpack) nor to GH pages.

Push your static Blazor WASM to Cloudflare pages -
[Tutorial](https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-deploy-blazor-webassembly-to-cloudflare-pages)

Literally zero problems happened - push to github, paste build command in cloudflare pages interface - Deploy